# Where are Skyrim screenshots saved?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

I just took a screenshot in *Skyrim*. The message in the corner says it was saved, but it does not say where...

Where are these saved on my computer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Should be *Program Files(x86)/Steam/SteamApps/Common/Skyrim*

Answer (score 8):

Right-click on the game in the Steam list, and click "View Screenshots". Then, click "Show on Disk" to open the directory where your screenshots are held:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata\<some_id>\760\remote\72850\screenshots`

Answer (score 2):

In case you have Skyrim installed via the disk the screenshots are stored in the root of your Skyrim installation directory, something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Skyrim`.

Comment: Skyrim is a Steamworks game. It does not work (legitimately) without Steam on the PC.

Comment: Perfectly possible: http://www.overclock.net/t/1164726/make-skyrim-install-from-dvd-instead-of-stupid-steam

Comment: That's installing from the disc instead of Steam, it still *uses* Steam. Makes the answer seem valid though.

Comment: You're right, I updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

In *Skyrim Special Edition*, when I press <kbd>F12</kbd>, it takes screenshots that are stored in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata\<some id>\760\remote\489830\screenshots`. When I press the <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> button on my keyboard, it takes screenshots stored in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Skyrim Special Edition`.

[image: C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Skyrim Special Edition]

[image: C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata<some id>\760\remote\489830\screenshots]

Definitely seems like there are just two different types of screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> to take a screenshot and then press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> and go into screenshots – it should be there. Works for me.

Comment: This doesn't tell you where it's stored, it just tells you how to access them in Steam .

Comment: Doesn't this only work while you're actually playing the game?

Answer (score 0):

Found them! I go into steam right click the game and click properties. Go to local files and then browse local files and they should pop up right there

Answer (score -2):

The correct location is in the same folder SkyrimSE.exe is located. Here is the screenshot

[image]

You see the file, screenshot0.png, screenshot1.png

Yap. That's the one. Because I install skyrim on drive D that's where it is.

I search for all possible locations. None of the other answers there works for me so maybe there is something about my set up that makes it fail

One location is

[image]

https://levelskip.com/rpgs/How-to-Take-Screenshots-in-Skyrim

It's not there. There is no folder skyrim in common

Another place that I look for

C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata<some_id>\760\remote\72850\screenshots

Right?

I found it

[image]

Yes there is one screenshot there.

However, the name of the screenshot file when I take screenshot in skyrim is clearly screenshot0.png, screenshot1.png. The only file there is 20200923161224_1.jpg

Also, only 1 screenshot there. I have other screenshot, namely of dragons.

So it seems that screenshots are not saved in one folder. If I go to map it is saved in C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata<some_id>\760\remote\72850\screenshots. Normal screenshots is saved in the skyrim directory

I cannot really find where skyrim is installed easily. Looking at shortcut of skyrim shows

steam://rungameid/489830

Where the hell it's located? Who knows. I know I installed skyrim on drive D so I found it anyway using a program called vortex. There is goes