# Where does Skyrim save screenshots to?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc, xbox-game-pass-for-pc

I just downloaded Skyrim from Xbox Game Pass and I want to know where it saves screenshots to.

Comment: Related: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38271/where-are-skyrim-screenshots-saved

Comment: Is there any way to tell where the install location of the game is?

Comment: @TimmyJim: I would be *very* surprised if it was saving screenshots to the install directory like regular Skyrim does. Game Pass is supposed to lock down the install directory IIRC (which is why modders avoid it like the plague).